# How to create bounds of a android LatLng (two points) in order to show at the top of screen? in android

Tags: android, google-maps, bounds, google-polyline

[image]

I have two points of LatLng coordinates. And I draw a polyline based on that coordinates . How can I fit that polyline drawing on top of the screen with zoomed out to view full line? Is LatLngBounds.Builder the correct solution for that?

these is my code i am using now

```
LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

//latlong  and latlong1 are my two points.

        String[] latlong = pickUp.split(",");
        LatLng location = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latlong[0]), Double.parseDouble(latlong[1]));
        String[] latlong1 = destination.split(",");
        LatLng location1 = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(latlong1[0]), Double.parseDouble(latlong1[1]));

        builder.include(location);
        builder.include(location1);


        LatLngBounds bounds = builder.build();
        int padding = 40; 
        CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        mMap.animateCamera(cu);
```

Comment: what do you mean by `fit that polyline drawing on top of the screen` ? can you provide a screenshot or example?

Comment: @Atef Hares edited the que please see now

Comment: you could use `LatLngBounds` constructor as well

Comment: @pskink how to show that at top of the screen like screen shot

Comment: @pskink the points appear at center

Comment: use [scrollBy](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory#scrollBy(float,%20float)) then - more [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/views)